# facebook api get my friends profile pic

Tags: php, facebook

Hi there I am creating an app and I want to display my friends profile picture, but what happens in my case is that my profile picture is displayed x the number of the friends that I have. Any idea of what I should change on my code ? Thanks.

```
   $uid = $facebook->$facebook->api('/me/friends/');

       //create the url
       $profile_pic =  "http://graph.facebook.com/".$uid."/picture";

      foreach($user_graph['data'] as $photokey => $photovalue){
     echo "<img src=\"" . $profile_pic . "\" />";
      }
```

Comment: what do you expect? you retrieve ONE picture, then use it for ALL of the friends.

Comment: Try `var_dump($uid);` and see it's not an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you have provided I see a couple of problems. Why are you calling `$facebook->$facebook->api()`? Surely that should be `$facebook->api('/me/friends/');`

Secondly, your api call returns an array, it looks like you are trying to treat `$uid` as a single value to me.

Also, If your loop works I imagine `$user_graph` must be defined elsewhere in your code.

I would probably just do something like this:

```
$friendlist = $facebook->api('/me/friends/');

foreach($friendlist["data"] as $value) {
    echo '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' . $value["id"] . '/picture"/>';
}
```

It's not going to look very neat but it should yield the result you were originally going for.